# Some colors don't change after switching themes (only in chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project that has a toggle feature to change the theme, but this toggler doesn't work correctly in certain circumstances. When I switch from a dark theme to a light theme, or vice versa, the colors remain unchanged until I hover over those elements.

This problem only occurs in Chrome, but not in Chrome incognito tab and Firefox!

Live Preview: https://sadeghrastgoo.github.io/Axies-NFT-Market-Place

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/SadeghRastgoo/Axies-NFT-Market-Place

_colors.scss:

```
:root {
  --primary-text-color: #fdfdfd;
  --bg-color: #14141f;
  --primary-color: #4e3fee;
  --gray-color: #adadb0;
  --icon-bg-color: #343444;
  --bg-color-2: #0d0d12;
  --line-color: #242431;
  --primary-color-2: #606067;
  --bg-black: #030303;
  --nav-color-1: #2c2c45;
}

.light-colors {
  --bg-color: #fdfdfd !important;
  --primary-text-color: #14141f !important;
  --gray-color: #919191 !important;
  --icon-bg-color: #fdfdfd !important;
  --bg-color-2: #9d9d9d !important;
  --line-color: #bfbfec !important;
  --primary-color-2: #d8d8dc !important;
  --bg-black: #f3f3f3 !important;
  --nav-color-1: #f1f0f0;

  .theme-light {
    fill: var(--primary-text-color) !important;
  }

  .btn--primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .btn--tertiary:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .feature__icon {
    color: var(--bg-color);
  }

  .footer {
    h4.text-lg {
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    background: #161616 !important;
    .social-icon svg path {
      fill: #000 !important;
    }
  }

  .card {
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;

    .like-tag {
      background: var(--primary-text-color);
      color: #fff;
    }
    .place-bid--active {
      background: #14141f !important;
    }
    .place-bid__checkbox {
      box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0 0 12px -2px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

script.js:

```
document.querySelector(".theme-light").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("light-colors");
});
document.querySelector(".theme-dark").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("light-colors");
});
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the dark theme first and then add the light theme (and vice versa)?

Comment: @Reporter Unfortunately no, because the way in which my light theme is applied is by overriding the default color scheme in :root

Comment: And wich elements do not change the color? Which "certain circumstances" are? I tried it out with chrome and cannot see hard errors.

Comment: @Reporter For example, the header text colors (For me, in Chrome 99 (Windows 11) it doesn't change after switching themes)

Answer (score 1):

i used a similar functionality in my website but i take a different approach,
this is how my approach looks like, i hope this can help you too

```
// Default theme is the one i have in local storage or dark theme when nothing is in the local storage
changeTheme(localStorage.theme || "dark");

let themes = {
    light: {
      "main-bg-color" : "#F5F5F5",
      "card-bg-color" : "#08D9D6",
      "font"          : "#252A34",
    },
    dark: {
      "main-bg-color" : "#23252e",
      "card-bg-color" : "#1c1e25",
      "font"          : "#fff",
    },
  };

// Toggle theme
function changeTheme(theme) {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    switchCheckbox.checked = theme === "light";

    for (let prop in themes[theme]) {
        // document.documentElement is the root element
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--" + prop, themes[theme][prop]);
    }
}

// My toggle switch 
switchCheckbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
    changeTheme(switchCheckbox.checked ? "light" : "dark");
});
```

Comment: Actually i was looking for a solution to my problem, but thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

> This problem only occurs in Chrome, but not in Chrome incognito tab and Firefox!

I believe this might have something to do with Google's cache. Try disabling your cache and then load the page again. You can disable it by clicking `ctrl`+`shift`+`j` on your keyboard, then go to the `Network` section and click on `Disable Cache`. [image]

Comment: this didn't fix the problem